Java keystore.load(null, null) very slow in Windows 10
The loading of keystore in Windows is very slow. It takes around 10 seconds to load all keystore in Windows-MY type of keystore.
I came across a few similar topics I encountered on Stack Overflow, like this.
I also tried to edit SecureRandom property like this post.
All solutions are ineffective. Here is my code to load keystore in Windows:
SunMSCAPI providerMSCAPI = new SunMSCAPI();
KeyStore ks = null;
try {
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", providerMSCAPI);
    ks.load(null, null);
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()){
        String aliasName = (String) aliases.nextElement();
        Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(aliasName);
        if(cert instanceof X509Certificate){
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate)cert;
            String certSn = x509Certificate.getSerialNumber().toString(16);
            Date effectiveDate = x509Certificate.getNotBefore();
            Date expireDate = x509Certificate.getNotAfter();
            String subjectName = null;
            String issueName = null;
            String uid = null;
            LdapName ldapSubject = new LdapName(x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().getName());
            LdapName ldapIssuer = new LdapName(x509Certificate.getIssuerDN().getName());
            for(Rdn rdn : ldapSubject.getRdns()) {
                if(rdn.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CN")) {
                    subjectName = rdn.getValue().toString();
                }
                if(rdn.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("UID")) {
                    uid = rdn.getValue().toString();
                }
                if(uid != null && subjectName != null){
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(Rdn rdn : ldapIssuer.getRdns()) {
                if(rdn.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CN")) {
                    issueName = rdn.getValue().toString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(uid != null){
                certList.add(new CertificateData(certSn, subjectName, issueName, effectiveDate, expireDate, uid));
            }
        }//end if
    }//end while
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    response.setErrors(e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (CertificateException e) {
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    response.setErrors(e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    response.setErrors(e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    response.setErrors(e.getLocalizedMessage());
} catch (InvalidNameException e) {
    //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    response.setErrors(e.getLocalizedMessage());
}

My environment:

Windows 10
Java 1.8

And my laptop has only two certificates in the Certificate store:
screenshot
How can I deal with this problem?

As far as I know, it shouldn't be necessary to create an instance of SunMSCAPI like that. What happens if you use KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY") instead?

it also takes as much time as not using SunMSCAPI , about 10-15s for ks.load(null, null)
